# Unable to fetch the entire column index based on the value using JSONPath finder in npm

Tags: node.js, jsonpath

I have the below response payload and I just want to check the amount == 1000 if it's matching then I just want to get the entire column as output.

**Sample Input:**

```
{
    "sqlQuery": "select SET_UNIQUE, amt as AMOUNT from transactionTable where SET_USER_ID=11651 ",
    "message": "2 rows selected",
    "row": [
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "22621264",
                    "name": "SET_UNIQUE"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1000",
                    "name": "AMOUNT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "column": [
                {
                    "value": "226064213",
                    "name": "SET_UNIQUE"
                },
                {
                    "value": "916",
                    "name": "AMOUNT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    "column": [
                    {
                        "value": "22621264",
                        "name": "SET_UNIQUE"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "1000",
                        "name": "AMOUNT"
                    }
                ]
```

The above sample I just want to fetch the entire column if the AMOUNT value will be 1000.

I just tried below to achieve this but no luck.

```
1. row[*].column[?(@.value==1000)].column
2. row[*].column[?(@.value==1000)]
```

I don't want to do this by using index. Because It will be change.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need nested expressions, which isn't something that's widely supported.  Something like

```
$.row[?(@.column[?(@.value==1000)])]
```

The inner expression returns matches for `value==1000`, then the outer expression checks for existence of those matches.

Another alternative that might work is

```
$.row[?(@.column[*].value==1000)]
```

but this assumes some implicit type conversions that may or may not be supported.